# Ruby on Rails: what performance can I realistically aim for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been building an application in Ruby on Rails 3, and I'm starting to worry about performance optimization. Now I hope that my question is not too subjective for this site, but I'm interested in facts, not a discussion, so here goes:

While I'm trying to get my views to render faster, there is one thing I simply do not know: What should I aim for? Given a reasonably complex page, what load time is realistic? I simply don't have any reference.

What I'm typically seeing for my application is something like this:

Completed 200 OK in 397ms (Views: 341.1ms | ActiveRecord: 17.7ms)

- This is on my production server, running Apache/Passenger.
- I am the only one (!) making requests on that server, it's a root server (not virtual), running Ubuntu, AMD Athlon 64 X2 5600+, 4 GB RAM
- That is, for most of my more complicated actions (not unusually complicated, just assume it's a paginated listing of 20 objects with 5 computed properties each or something) the ActiveRecord times are almost always fine (<20-30ms), but the "views" number is usually >200 ms.
- Now, to my question: When I started using RoR my expectation (maybe unrealistic) was that for most consumer-oriented applications with average complexity (let's say something like Facebook, Twitter, etc. WITHOUT the millions of users) I would get < 20 ms load times as long as I was the only one making requests, and that for a single server load times would only approach 100ms or more if there were lots of people making requests at the same time.
- My expectation was also that database requests would be the major bottleneck, since all the rest is just relatively simple computations without any real complexity. I thought that it might take 10ms to get all the objects from the database, and then maybe another 5 ms to run the controller code, build the view, etc.

Since I've never been in charge of any production app, I don't know if this expectation was in any way realistic. So I would like somebody with experience point out to me what my realistic expectation should be.

- (e.g. "pretty much everything but really nasty stuff should render in 50 ms tops as long as you are the only one making requests")
- or ("actually 300 ms is not unusual for RoR applications, even if you're the only user")
- or ("Are you kidding? I get < 10 ms with 150 concurrent requests on a smaller server than yours. There must be something very wrong with your app)

Again, I hope this is not too subjective, but I'm not really interested in an opinion of whether or not RoR is fast, I want facts from someone with more experience on what numbers are average and to be expected from production RoR applications. Otherwise I simply have no clue at what point I should stop optimizing and just accept that I'll never get 10 ms load times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting view times < 20ms on a $20/month linode server. That's well-optimized code, for a request of medium complexity, running on JRuby. You haven't hit Rails' performance limits by any means. Time to use a profiler and see what's taking so long.

Answer (score 6):

Gosh, I'm not sure I'm the one to answer this, but since I've been around these waters enough times, I may have an incomplete idea of things to look at.

First of all, the response times is pretty subjective.  Meaning, it's good enough if it's good enough for you.  From my experience, pages resembling your description seem to take about as much time as what you're describing.  So, you're not orders of magnitude off in either direction.

If you want to optimize your view renders with your current architecture, your next step is [here](http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails), I think.  Greg Pollack does a great job breaking this stuff down for you and will make sure you're on track.  You'll be sure to get your assets cached and your stack fine-tuned.  That'll be your most practical general advice.

If you're willing to look at your deployment architecture, Ilya Grigorik raises some great questions in [this article](http://www.igvita.com/2010/06/07/rails-performance-needs-an-overhaul/) and then answers them with [Goliath](http://www.igvita.com/2011/03/08/goliath-non-blocking-ruby-19-web-server/).  If your bottlenecks are speeding up your server-client round trip, that's probably the approach to do.

I try to pay attention to anything Aaron Patterson says about performance, like in [this talk](http://confreaks.net/videos/427-rubyconf2010-zomg-why-is-this-code-so-slow).  He's going to teach general optimization ideas, most of them for your server-side code.  You may catch a few things that relate to your current problem.

I was pulled aside by a former co-worker at [MWRC](http://mtnwestrubyconf.org/) this year and told that I'm absolutely nuts if I'm not building with JRuby these days.  It's a bit of a commitment, and I've resisted making major changes like that until I have truly painful response times, which I don't, and it doesn't sound like you're having either.  However, JRuby's a very mainstream thing to do now, and you and I will likely embrace this for some projects at some point in the future.

So, bottom line, I think you're in the realm of a spry app as you are.  I think I'd work down these resources in the order I presented them.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful post. I can't accept it since there are no numbers in it, but the insight is very valuable.

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing what you're rendering, it's hard to comment on the performance, but I would venture to say that 200ms is very high. Don't forget that the debug information in your logs can be a little misleading: if you're querying your DB or some external resource from within a view, as opposed to preloading that data in your controller, then that time will be attributed to view rendering.

Common culprits: you load Model X in your model, but then access an association in your view which triggers a bunch of selects under the hood. The time to fetch Model x is low, but the associated records will show up as "view time".

In other words, dig into the logs and if its actually your view code, then bring up a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your 200 ms view time is abnormal, or even high in any way.

However, you have room for improvement. You say " (not unusually complicated, just assume it's a paginated listing of 20 objects with 5 computed properties each or something)"

To me, that's 100 operations that could be pre-calculated, and would speed up your view rendering time.

Finally -- Rendering time doesn't usually have a direct correlation to number of users. Under most deployments, as a request comes in, it is handled by a process and then responded to. Other requests wait until the first is completed before they are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Use static content where possible.  Outside of that, use caching where possible, at the highest possible level, preferably at the page level.  When content can't be cached, try to get -something- static or cacheable back to the user quickly.  You might, for instance, serve up a static page with the basic layout, and an animated busy-image where the content belongs, and then use JavaScript to load the dynamic content.