# How to add a parameter when performing JWT issuer-validation in ASP.NET Core 5 with AuthenticationBuild.AddJwtBearer()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I am autheticating my API users using externally-generated JWTs provided by an Azure Active Directory B2C provider. When I attempt to authenticate using a valid JWT, I recieve the following stack trace error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from:
'https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

In my code, shown at the bottom, the `addJwtBearer()` method is taking an issuer URL as one of its parameters. When it performs issuer validation, it adds a `/.well-known` suffix.

```
// Original
"https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/"

// With suffix
"https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

The issue is that the endpoint requires an additional parameter, the AD user flow ID, to perform the validation, as show below:

```
//Correct address, with paramter
"https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_ropc"

//Sent address
"https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

If I attempt to add the parameter in the original URL, the suffix is still added after the parameter, which malforms the URL. Any advice on how to overcome this? Feel free to ask for clarifications to my sleep-deprived madness :)

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearerConfiguration(
                    "https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/",
                    "<audience_id>"
                );
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    ...
}
```

**JwtConfig.cs**

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddJwtBearerConfiguration(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string issuer, string audience)
{
    return builder.AddJwtBearer(options => 
    {
        options.Authority = issuer; // https://<blade_id>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/
        options.Audience = audience;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ClockSkew = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 30) 
        };
        // Code for handling challenges
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418620/ruby-on-rails-what-performance-can-i-realistically-aim-for)

Answer (score -1):

You really do not want to be using JWT in 2021, and you should not be passing this onto your API consumers. Modern microservice architecture should not be susceptible to a single point of failure, you need to be using safe, decentralized and developer-agnostic security token.

[Here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/03/23/microservice-security-patterns) is an article describing best practice microservice security patterns you will benefit from studying, and [here](https://github.com/paragonie/paseto) you may find a reference PHP implementation of PASETO, which is one such modern microservice security token. I would encourage you to study these resources, as clients of your API do not have to inherit your implementation complexities. [Here](https://github.com/instructure/paseto) is my [memory safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/meet-safe-and-unsafe.html) implementation of PASETO in the Rust programming language.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).